# Generate XML-String dynamically from NSObjects

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, xml-parsing, nsobject

I am trying to dynamically generate one single XML-String with the attributes of one or more NSObjects.

I am using WonderXML but I do not understand how I am able to adjust the structure of the XML-Strings that WonderXML produces.

Here is my code so far:

**Object:**

```
@interface Getraenke_Object : NSObject {    
@protected
    NSString *item_id;
    NSString *menge;
    NSString *categorie;

    NSString *name;
    NSString *preis;    
    NSString *image; 
}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *item_id;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *menge;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *categorie;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *preis;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *image;

@end
```

**m-File:**

```
//-----------------Converting the Objects to XML-Strings--------------

    XmlParser *parser = [[XmlParser alloc] init];
    NSString *meinXmlString;

    for(int i=0; i<getraenkeArray.count; i++)
    {
        meinXmlString = [parser toXml:[getraenkeArray objectAtIndex:i] andTag:@"Getraenk" inNameSpace:@"table_info"];
    }

    NSLog(@"meinXmlString: %@\n", meinXmlString);
```

**This is how meinXmlString looks like:**

meinXmlString:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Getraenke_Object xmlns="table_info"><name>Chateau_d_Angludet</name>
<menge>1</menge><preis>119</preis><image>Rotwein.png</image>
<categorie>getraenke</categorie><item_id>101</item_id>
</Getraenke_Object>
```

**but it should look like:**

testXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Table_info><table_id>1</table_id><action_id>3</action_id><Bestellliste>
<item><categorie>getraenke</categorie><item_id>100</item_id><menge>1</menge></item>
<item><categorie>getraenke</categorie><item_id>2</item_id><menge>1</menge></item>
</Bestellliste></Table_info>
```

I hopefully described my problem understandable.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You create an XML string for each object and only end up keeping the last one.

It appears that WonderXML is creating an XML document automatically based on the properties and their names in the object you pass in.

Since it appears that you want your XML to include all objects in the array, try passing the whole array to a single call to `parser toXml`. You don't want a loop.

Of course it may be easier to create the XML yourself. Just create an `NSMutableString` and add the text of the tags that you want.